# После перезагрузки vps не стартует mysql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, vps

На vps поднял веб-сервер  php7, apache, mysql.

Все работало, по глупости решил перезагрузить сервер для снижения показателя Inodes (после оптимизации картинок на 5GB )
В общем apache php стартнули , а mysql никак.

Пробовал и стартовать и рестартовать, но без толку.

Вот что пишет sudo service mysql status

```
root@11207:/home# sudo service mysql status                                                                    
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql; bad; vendor preset: enabled)                                             
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-11-07 21:08:11 EET; 30s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)                                                                       
  Process: 6335 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 07 21:07:40 11207.s.hostens.cloud mysqld[6507]: 181107 21:07:40 [ERROR] Aborting
Nov 07 21:07:40 11207.s.hostens.cloud mysqld[6507]:                                                            
Nov 07 21:07:40 11207.s.hostens.cloud mysqld[6507]: 181107 21:07:40 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Nov 07 21:07:40 11207.s.hostens.cloud mysqld[6507]:                                                            
Nov 07 21:07:40 11207.s.hostens.cloud mysqld_safe[6511]: mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended 
Nov 07 21:08:11 11207.s.hostens.cloud mysql[6335]:    ...fail!                                                 
Nov 07 21:08:11 11207.s.hostens.cloud systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1  
Nov 07 21:08:11 11207.s.hostens.cloud systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server
Nov 07 21:08:11 11207.s.hostens.cloud systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.                    
Nov 07 21:08:11 11207.s.hostens.cloud systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Что же делать то, помогите

Comment: смотри логи мускуля (скорей всего в `/var/log/mysql/*`)...

Answer (score 0):

в общем на сервере Inodes был занят на 100%, это не давало нормально работать серверу.